# Need to create button in new experience sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online

Need to create button in new experience sharepoint page.. Any idea how to create ?? 
I have tried with image and then gave link to the image.. But except this any other idea will be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new button in the new experience page by using SPFx solution to add custom code in the new experience page.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Use an SPFx Application Customizer to add JavaScript (e.g. header) to every page in a site](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html)

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)